# Invalid token error while trying to access an API using python

Tags: python, api, curl, authorization

I am trying to access an API which is :

```
curl "api_endpoint_here"
  -H "Authorization: Token token=YOURAPIKEY"
```

I am using Python and tried this:

```
response = requests.get('https://app.resemble.ai/api/v1/projects', headers= {'Authorization': 'Token' , 'token' :'my_API_KEY'})
```

I have used the actual API key in place of my_API_KEY.

I am getting an error saying 'Unauthorized -- Your API key is wrong'
the key is correct.

Comment: Try `{'Authorization': 'Token token=my_API_KEY'}`! They use a strange auth header format IMHO.

Comment: in string `-H "Authorization: Token token=YOURAPIKEY"` you have only one header but in `{'Authorization': 'Token' , 'token' :'my_API_KEY'}` you create two headers - and it is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

This helped:
headers = {'Authorization': 'Token my_API_KEY '}